# Change color based on firebase value within flutter decoration

Tags: firebase, flutter, colors, switch-statement

I have a decoration that I wish to change of based on a value return from firebase.
Currently, I have my decoration like below

```
decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                      left: BorderSide(
                          color: getColor(task.status), width: 5))),
```

This is my switch statement which I was hoping would return the right colour

```
Color getColor(Color status) {
  switch (status.toString()) {
    case 'Draft':
      return const Color.fromRGBO(255, 203, 51, 1);
    case 'Posted':
      return const Color.fromRGBO(10, 217, 163, 1);
    case 'Offered':
      return const Color.fromRGBO(20, 152, 204, 1);
    case 'Assigned':
      return const Color.fromRGBO(14, 116, 178, 1);
    case 'Overdue':
      return const Color.fromRGBO(222, 80, 66, 1);
    default:
      return const Color.fromRGBO(144, 163, 167, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please try to add more details, looks like your code should work. Are you passing correct value into getColor() method. What error you're getting. Are you getting default color?

Comment: these are the 2 errors `Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception.` and `Invalid constant value.`

Comment: Okay, please try to add images / error logs in question. That'll help to solver your error.

Comment: You can't use const on BoxDecoration since not all its props are constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getColor(Color status)
```

This above method says that you are supposed to pass Color type and then you're trying to convert into string and matching it with "Draft", "Posted" etc. There are no colors by that name my friend.

First if you're getting error like "Invalid constant value". Please remove const from your code. It's not needed.

Your getColor() method looks just fine and should work like your're expecting. You just need to pass correct value (may be not Color type but simple string should work).

I tried your code on flutter dev and it works.

[image: This one is where I'm calling your getColor method, I just tried simple string as an argument]

[image]